# Functional test unable to locate template

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to write a test verifying my controller's action. When tested manually, the code executes as expected. However, my test raises an error because it is unable to locate a template I am attempting to render.

Snippet from my controller code:

```
response = {:success => true}

response[:html] = {}
response[:html][:list] = render_to_string :partial => "data_source", :locals => {:data_source => @data_source}

respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => response}
end
```

My test:

```
before do
  @data_source = FactoryGirl.create :data_source, :facebook_fan_page, :account_id => @account.id, :user_id => @user.id
  post :delete, :format => :json, :id => @data_source.id
end

it "should disable the data source" do
  assert_equal false, @data_source.reload.enabled?
end
```

The error message:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing partial data_sources/data_source,
>   capture/data_source, application/data_source with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in:
>   * "/Users/me/code/my_app/app/views"   * "/Users/me/code/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/konacha-3.0.0/app/views"
>   from
>   /Users/me/code/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in
>   `find'

There is definitely a partial in the app/view/data_sources directory "_data_source.html.haml".

Why can't the test find the partial? I suspect a setup issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing a json request, `render_to_string` is looking for a json template. Try this:

```
render_to_string :partial => "data_source", :formats => [:html], :locals => {:data_source => @data_source}
```

Comment: Thank you! I see the issue now. Digging into my code, running locally when I make the request it is of format */* and so it is rendering the partially correctly, but my test was requesting :json.